# "This post is deleted and cannot be edited." text on a totally blank page

Tags: bug, editing, review, deleted-answers

I have an error to report.

Today, I have started for the first time to review other users' questions and answers. So the error I am talking about never happened to me and I don't know if it was encountered by anyone else. Still, I think it's better to report it.

After editing someone's answer and clicking the "Submit" button, I was directed to a page having only this message on it:

"This post is deleted and cannot be edited."

While I can understand the meaning of the message and the cause of it, I can't understand why it appeared on a totally blank page. I was simply thrown out from Askubuntu website! I had to click on the "Back" button in my browser in order to get back on it.

My guess is that Askubuntu has some problems with its HTML codes, which it should be fixed.

---

Here, in the screenshot, you can see the message:

[image: Error message on a blank page]

...In order to get back, I clicked "back" button. As you can see, I had no other solution.

[image: In order to get back on Askubuntu I clicked on back button in browser]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just a guess (I've had a sort of similar experience with reviewing), but maybe somebody else reviewed at the same time, and they deleted it.

Comment: @CarlH Yes, but then it seems that something "short-circuits" the HTML codes of the website every time when two people edit the same text. It's not a normal behaviour.

Comment: Do you know what post it was (a description with keywords (and roughly the time it was deleted) could help those with mod tools look at it)

Comment: @Wilf Luckily, I know it very well. The post in discussion is exactly the one that can be viewed in the second screenshot. More exactly, it's the answer  provided by an user called "Element Tech".

Comment: @Wilf And I have the time registered on the screenshot file h:14 m:29 s:48 Bucharest time (2h+ Greenwich).